# How to make selenium interact with new HTML elements of the new page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the 'Download file in CSV format' which is at top-right of the data table of the new page or how can I copy the entire table and then past it in a file with selenium or other better way to download or copy past. The problem is that code is working only with the HTML elements of the old page but not with the elements of the new page. so I also want to know how to make the same selenium code woke with new HTML elements of the new page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

##chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
##chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
##driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm')

equity_name = browser.find_element_by_name('symbol')
equity_name.send_keys('YESBANK')

v = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#rdDateToDate")
v.click()

date_from = browser.find_element_by_id('fromDate')
date_from.send_keys('01-03-2019')

date_to = browser.find_element_by_id('toDate')
date_to.send_keys('01-05-2019')

get_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="get"]').click()
get_table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/table').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm')

# insert yesbank string
equity_name = browser.find_element_by_name('symbol')
equity_name.send_keys('YESBANK')

#select radio button
v = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#rdDateToDate")
v.click()

#insert from date
date_from = browser.find_element_by_id('fromDate')
date_from.send_keys('01-03-2019')

#insert to date
date_to = browser.find_element_by_id('toDate')
date_to.send_keys('01-05-2019')

# submit form
get_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="get"]').click()

# wait util load table data and csv file
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "download-data-link")))

#find csv file link parent tag by class name, finding parent tag to child tag because csv file link tag does not contain class name or id.
parentElement = browser.find_element_by_class_name('download-data-link')

# find csv file link by parent tag
link = parentElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

#download csv file
print(link[0].click())
```

where `"download-data-link"` span tag class and `a` `csv file link which` is inside span tag

**Scrape** table data:

add top of the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

add after `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "download-data-link")))` line code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
div = page_soup.find("div", {'class':"tabular-data-historic"})
table = div.find("table").find("tbody")
for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
   for td in tr.find_all("td"):
      print(td.text)
```

Comment: would you mind if u can explain me the working of each line you added? plz

Comment: if I want to copy the entire table and paste it in new file how can I do it??

Comment: @vardhan negi  You already getting all table data by a csv file, why do you want to scrap table data.

Comment: in some case in other website if I don't get the download file option.so for that scenario I want to know it in advance. also thanks in advance for the help

Comment: @vardhan negi  You should learn python `Beautifulsoup` library to scrap table data.